# Will shure 520DX green bullet harmonica mic work with the guitar pedal effect?

Tags: sound, electronics

I plan to buy shure 520DX mic to plug it with my guitar pedal Behringer SF300 superfuzz. I know that if I was to plug my shure sm57 then the signal would be too weak, but since it's a green bullet mic that has high impedance output and needs at least 100k ohm load, then I wonder if it will work just fine with my guitar pedal. What do you think?

After it's done I'd send the signal from the fuzz effect to the audio interface with the instrument setting. Or maybe line setting would be better? I read that the fuzz effect's pedal output is 1k ohm so line level input has 10 times more (10k). Instrument input would have over 1000 times more, because it's around milion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s high impedance. 1/4” unbalanced plug. So I don’t see why not.

Comment: Yeah it's uually plugged to the amp that wants the high impedance, soo I guess it should be fine if I plug it to the pedal. Then I'd send it to the audio interface with instrument setting, right? or maybe line setting would be better?